# Accessing personal data directly on Mendeley

Tags: mendeley

Is there any way to have access to users' personal data without always having a need to authenticate trough the (rather heavy) OAuth process (i.e. I would like to do some cronjobs to my collections and trying to figure out, how could this be done).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to authenticate using OAuth for all API requests.

However, for recurring cron jobs, you can simplify the process by storing your refresh token the first time you authenticate, and using that to get an access token for future requests.  This means that you don't have to log in every time.

See the "Refreshing access tokens" section of http://dev.mendeley.com/reference/topics/authorization_auth_code.html for more information.